# Thread started in a Tkinter Callback block the entire interface

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, trace

(I removed the old description after finding new informations, I don't believe it is needed anymore).

So, I have a Tkinter interface with actually three button : Run, Stop, Step.

The Run button start a thread that runs various functions, but need an input on the Step button to continue its execution. This is done by waiting a Python event, setted when you press the Step button.

However, despite having `time.sleep` while waiting for my event, my code doesn't return to the Tkinter interface and the whole program is blocked. If I remove the wait condition, the thread runs until it stops, then I have access to my interface.

I believe that the callback function `RunButton()` doesn't return until the thread is over which is why my interface would be locked. Is there any way to pass this issue?

Here is my current code :

```
import sys
import signal
import inspect
import threading
import multiprocessing 
import Queue
import time
import Tkinter

class tk_interface(Tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self,parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):
        self.grid()

        self.button1 = Tkinter.Button(self,text=u"Run",command=self.RunButton)
        self.button1.grid(column=0,row=0)

        self.button2 = Tkinter.Button(self,text=u"Stop",command=self.StopButton)
        self.button2.grid(column=1,row=0)

        self.button3 = Tkinter.Button(self,text=u"Step",command=self.StepButton)
        self.button3.grid(column=2,row=0)

        self.cmd_box = Tkinter.Text(self, wrap='word', height=20)
        self.cmd_box.grid(column=0,row=1,columnspan=3)

        self.resizable(False,False)
        self.update()
        self.ReadReportQueue()

    def RunButton(self):
        thr1.run()

    def StopButton(self):
        self.destroy()

    def StepButton(self):
        cmd_step.set()

    def ReadReportQueue(self):
        sys.stdout=sys.__stdout__
        if not reportQueue.empty():
            catch_message(self.cmd_box,reportQueue)
        self.after(200, self.ReadReportQueue)


class debug_thread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, name):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.name = name

    def trace_calls(self, frame, event, arg):
        if event != 'call':
            return

        co = frame.f_code
        func_name = co.co_name
        file_name = co.co_filename

        if func_name in ['loop_func']:
            return self.trace_lines

    def trace_lines(self, frame, event, arg):
        if event != 'line' and event != 'return':
            return

        co = frame.f_code
        func_name = co.co_name
        file_name = co.co_filename
        source = inspect.getsourcelines(co)[0]

        #cmd_step.wait()

        while not cmd_step.is_set():
            time.sleep(0.2)

        cmd_step.clear()
        print('Call to %s on line %s of %s' % (func_name, frame.f_lineno, co.co_filename))

    def loop_func(self):
        for i in range(0,3):
            print("Loop number %d\n" %i)

    def run(self):
        print "Started thread"
        sys.stdout = reportQueue
        sys.settrace(self.trace_calls)
        self.loop_func()
        print "Exiting " + self.name


class StdoutQueue(Queue.Queue):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Queue.Queue.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    def write(self, msg):
        self.put(msg)

    def flush(self):
        sys.__stdout__.flush()


def catch_message(text_widget, queue):
    text_widget.insert(Tkinter.INSERT,queue.get())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    cmd_step = threading.Event()
    cmd_step.clear()

    reportQueue = StdoutQueue()

    thr1 = debug_thread('Thread 1')

    app = simpleapp_tk(None)
    app.title('Debug App')

    while True:
        app.update_idletasks()
        app.update()
        print "updating..."
```

Comment: You call `thr1.run()` directly rather than `thr1.start()`, so you never actually start a second thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a thread by inheriting from `threading.Thread`, you provide the code that should be run in the thread by overriding `Thread.run`. However, `debug_thread.run` is still a normal method. When you call `thr1.run()`, you're only executing the code declared in `debug_thread.run`, which doesn't start a separate thread. To start a separate thread, you need to use `thr1.start()`, which will create a new thread and call your `run` method within the new thread.

An alternative to inheriting from `threading.Thread` is to pass the function you want to call in a the new thread as an argument to the `threading.Thread` constructor.

```
def run_in_thread(step_event, stop_event):
    local_data = 1
    while not stop_event.is_set():
        local_data = do_step(local_data)
        step_event.wait()
        step_event.clear()

step_event = threading.Event()
stop_event = threading.Event()

thread = threading.Thread(target=run_in_thread, args=(step_event, stop_event))
thread.start()
```

To step the threaded function, just set `step_event`, to stop it and let the thread terminate, set `stop_event` so the loop will break *then* set `step_event` so the thread will check the loop condition again.

The two `Event`s are passed as thread arguments so that they don't need to be globals.